# CJuiDatepicker hide on select

Tags: php, yii, datepicker, hide, onselect

I'm trying to force the CJuiDatepicker to hide after I select the date. Nothing works. How could I achieve it?

Here's my actual code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'confirmStart',
            'options' => array(
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                'showButtonPanel' => false,
                'onSelect' => 'js:function() {
                        $("#Projects_confirmStart").datepicker("hide");
                    }
                    ',
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Try to check with `'onSelect'=>'js:function() {console.log($("#Projects_confirmStart").length}'`, for be sure that the selector is correct.

Comment: Hm, it seems like it's not working at all cause it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in my test Yii app. Check your program with mozilla firebug. You may get error in console when you select the date. May be your datepicker functionality is effecting by some other plugins/scripts.

Comment: I checked it ofcourse but no - there were no errors. Maybe the reason is that there are 3 datepickers on the page?

Comment: You can add multiple date pickers in a page.

Comment: I know, I have 3 of them. I'm just looking for a reason of not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'fechaAdq',
    'language' => 'es',
    'i18nScriptFile' => 'jquery-ui-i18n.min.js',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'id' => 'FMAIDetalleAdq_fechaAdq',
        'size' => '10', * *'onChange' => 'jQuery("#FMAIDetalleAdq_fechaAdq").datepicker("hide")' * *
    ) ,
    'defaultOptions' => array(
        'showOn' => 'focus',
        'showOtherMonths' => true,
        'selectOtherMonths' => true,
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'showButtonPanel' => true,
    ) ,
    'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'language' => 'es',
    ) ,
) , true);
```